# In django1.7 , Can one many to many relationship have another many to many relation?

Tags: many-to-many, relationship, django-1.7

In Django 1.7 , Can one many to many relationship have another many to many relation ?

```
class KeyValues(models.Model):
    value=models.IntegerField(max_length=1,blank=True)

class Key(models.Model):
        position=models.IntegerField(max_length=1,default=0,blank=True)
        keyValues= key=models.ManyToManyField(KeyValues)

class FileDetails(models.Model):
    fileId = models.CharField(max_length = 100,primary_key=True,db_index=True)
    key=models.ManyToManyField(Key)
```

I wanted to do this type of relation , But I'm getting an error ,

> ERRORS:
>   cloud.Key: (models.E003) The model has two many-to-many relations through the intermediate model 'cloud.Key_key'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful.... when you write the code !

> keyValues= key=models.ManyToManyField(KeyValues)

make no sense !!